# Extract multiple file names with specific paths & exitensions from text

Tags: regex

Given a sample text:

```
sometext /uploads/01/03/file.jpgmoretext and then some /uploads/44/93/anotherfile.png and yet /uploads/03/26/somefile.jpg
```

But this extracted from the first /uploads to the final .jpg
I want to extract 3 files... how do I say "the closes extension"?

I tried regex of "/uploads.*(.jpg|jpeg|png|gif)"
Expected 3 results, but got one long one.

Answer (score 2):

Because your `.*` is greedy and it will match until the last occurrence. Add a `?` to make it non greedy would help. And you should add dot to each extension part in OR group to avoid false result

```
/uploads.*?(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IYm9Si/1)

**Edit:** A cleaner regex to match multiple extensions case in OP's comments`:

```
\/uploads.*?(?:\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)+
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YxYH32/1)

Comment: Thank you.   I discovered a new problem...
if the text contains
/uploads/2015/07/josh?ssl=1">tick.jpg or /uploads/2015/07/josh.jpeg.jpg the match fails; am I hoping for too much?

Comment: @joshassing which language are you using. The first one `/uploads/2015/07/josh?ssl=1">tick.jpg` works with python, other language may need espace the first slash `/uploads`. To solve the second one, here is my attempt `\/uploads.*?(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)*(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)`. See it here [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/e3BktP/1)

Comment: @joshassing a cleaner version with non capturing group `?:` and match one or many `+` for the extension part: `\/uploads.*?(?:\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)+` [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YxYH32/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could match only non whitespace chars in a non greedy way using `\S*?` and shorten the pattern to an alternation preceded by the dot `\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)`

```
/uploads\S*?\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b0nHoH/1)